# SSRS report upload to on premise CRM 2016 from Visual studio 2017 is not working?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I use Reporting Services in visual studio 2017 for CRM 2016,

My initial plan was to export a Fetch XML file of CRM query > import to visual studio (create data source and dataset) > create report. Once done with report then add report to CRM. > Add report in CRM > existing file and then select “rdl” file from source folder of Visual Studio report file.

I was not able to use Fetch XML query and got the error " Could not create a list of fields for the query" while creating the dataset.

After getting this error instead of using Fetch xml I wrote query and pulled data from CRM database. Using SQL data connection , data source and data set.

I created my report in Visual studio 2017 but I cant run the reports on CRM 2016 I get error like process aborted

Any help on how to use vs 2017 report services for CRM 2016 will help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I learned and found while I was creating my SSRS report for on premise CRM.
While working with on premise crm you have ability to access the actual database to run your query and generate report, for CRM 2016 only old versions of Visual studio works.

The most important point is that you should use Filtered views/tables because filtered views recognizes user access and will work once you upload your report to CRM all my other reports generated from tables were working fine but they were showing nothing after being uploaded to CRM

Answer (score 0):

It will not work. You will need Visual Studio 2015 and SSRS reporting authorization of latest version.

Why VS2015 and not 2017 and 2019 because SSDT tools for reporting with Dynamics crm has not been updated added for them.

Long story short you will have to use VS2015 and created report with it.

Here is link for [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/deploy/microsoft-dynamics-365-reporting-requirements).

Comment: Thank you for having the time to look into this. I have installed VS 2012 with BIDS. I have downloaded some custom reports which were already existed and when I make the change in report and upload it works fine but when I change the datasource table from same database it does not work